# Filter characters in this RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression to match a valid name: `/^['"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+$/.test(name)`

I'm having trouble figuring out how to transform this match style regex into one designed to filter out invalid characters using `replace`.

Ideally I would like to be able to take an invalid name in `name`, run it through the `replace` to replace any invalid characters, and then have the original test return true no matter what (as invalid characters will be filtered out).

Comment: Why run a replace, just strict your regex to the characters you want to allow..

Comment: Building on @hwnd's comment, what are your valid characters? Or, if that's easier, what are your invalid characters?

Comment: Use two regular exp's, one to find partially ok names, one to fix the name. A callback is really all you should need. If JS can't do that, you have to sit in a loop and rebuild the string yourself. Oh, wait this is not strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a negated character class by adding a `^` in front:

```
name.replace(/[^'"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g, "")
```

Example:

```
var name = "'41%!\u2000abc";
var sanitized = name.replace(/[^'"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g, "");
console.log(/^['"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+$/.test(name)); // false
console.log(/^['"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+$/.test(sanitized)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^['"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+$/
```

The `+` at the end tells you to match a at least 1 or multiple characters of the types inside the brackets. The `^` at the beginning in combination with the `$` at the end tells to match the whole input from its start to its end. So given regex matches a string consisting of only the characters of the set.

What you want is this:

```
/[^'"\s\-.*0-9\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g
```

`[^]` means to NOT match whatever is inside the brackets and is the opposite of `[]`.